# iOS : how to use an asset with a shadow as a button image and make the shadow part not tappable?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have an asset representing a button with a shadow below. I want to make only the blue part tappable. Is there an easy way to do so?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You really don't want to make the button part the tappable part?

Comment: Hi, sorry if I was unclear, I had added the red part only to show the square part of the image I want to be tappable but it's actually not part of the image, what I want to do is to make the blue part of the button clickable (and not the shadow below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a drop shadow programmatically like this:

```
button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
button.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

so, swap out a version of the button asset that doesn't have the built-in shadow, and add the shadow as above. The new shadow will not change the tappable area of the button, no matter the size/offset.